# How do I send a fax using a fax modem in Ubuntu?

Tags: modem, fax

How do I use my modem to send a fax from my laptop where ubuntu is installed. How do I "print" to a fax modem to send a fax

Answer (score 1):

You can install `efax` software by running in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install efax
```

If you need GUI for that, install it by

```
sudo apt-get install efax-gtk
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

> efax

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/efax/

Remember to select your Ubuntu version first.

Comment: How do you select 14.04 or 15.04 there?

Comment: Oh! I see now, that only versions 10.04 up to 13.10 are listed there, so installing in the terminal is probably the best way to go

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center can be used too.

Comment: Link broken, redirects to https://snapcraft.io/store which makes no mention of 'fax' anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

watch out for the constantly updated article

"How to send faxes directly from within LibreOffice?"

This will definitely answer your question in detail.